# Trigger AWS Autoscale automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I have an Autoscale Web Application in AWS. When I don't use it, I terminated EC2 instances automatically with Lambda (with Cloudwatch). But I couldn't find an automatic structure to trigger it again.

What I have tried.

- I tried with Cloudwatch but I have to wait after the first request. It's not suitable for my setup.
- I trigger ELB by redirecting the requests coming to port 80 to Lambda and then redirect my main project 443, but it didn't seem very healthy.

If you have other suggestions or services I can use, can you share them?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve, then how you're trying to achieve it. Right now it's not clear what you want. Autoscaling should be controlling the number of instances for you, in most cases you shouldn't need lambda or other to do that.

Comment: @AlexD I did not know this link. Thank you :))

Comment: @Tim Minimum 1 instance has to run in AWS. That's why I set it to "0" with lambda, because I don't need an instance if it is not in use. If there is no instance running on the AutoScale side, I want to trigger it from the LB, but this can't be done with Cloudwatch because Autoscale is up and running in 10 seconds. But Cloudwatch handles it in 1 minute.

Comment: Again - can you please explain what you're trying to achieve. When is it "in use"? Is it a scheduled time? Is it based on requests? Is is just when you decide to turn it on?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to emulate serverless scale to zero with autoscaling. You can probably achieve this with one proxying lambda and another which switches ALB from sending traffic to lambda or EC2 directly depending on if there is an instance running. But you'll probably hit a lot of corners.